# How to create a function in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I am new to coding and I am learning python. I’m trying to write a simple program to test my skills, but I’m having some difficulties with it; I want to turn it into a function in order to make the program cleaner, but I get this error: http://prntscr.com/im5pt7

Here is what I want to put inside a function:

```
name = input(str("\nFull Name: "))       
position = input(str("Position at the company: "))
print("\nConfirm Staff Data:\n")
name_confirm = "Name: %s"%(name)
position_confirm = "Position: %s"%(position)
print(name_confirm)
print(position_confirm)
confirmAns = input("Is the information right? (Y/N)")
if confirmAns == "y" or confirmAns == "Y":
    message = "\nSearching for %s"%(name)
    print(message)
    hoursWorked = int(input("Insert hours worked: "))
    if hoursWorked <= 0:
            print("Please insert a valid number")
    elif hoursWorked > 0:
            print("\nCalculete Paycheck")
            hourRate = int(input("Insert the rate of each hour worked: "))
            bonus = input("If a bonus was given insert it here: ")
            fine = input("If a fine was given insert it here: ")
            print('\n')
            payment = hoursWorked*hourRate-int(fine)+int(bonus)
            paymentMsg = "Your Payment is: $%d"%(payment)
            print(paymentMsg)
elif confirmAns == "n" or confirmAns == "N":
    ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, "The software will close to avoid slowness.", "Warning", 1) 
else:
    print("Please answer with Y or N")
```

I've tried [**this**](https://pastebin.com/i7yxfMtL) but it did not work.
Here is all the code (working but with out the function so I need to copy and paste code): https://pastebin.com/PA9mxMkk

Comment: Your indentation is not proper. Please learn python indentation.

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is that the function as other statements needs to hold it's code into a new indentation level

```
print('a')

def test(var):
    print(var)
```

not this way

```
print('a')
def test(var):
print(var)
```

because this way it will give you the error that you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

The first step which is often difficult in learning python in understanding indentation.

for example.

```
def hello_world(world):
    print("hello ", world)
    #your function code goes here.

#you need to indent back to be out of function block.
hello_world("there!")

out: hello there
```

so in your case it should be like this.

```
def AnsNo():
    name = input(str("\nFull Name: "))      
    position = input(str("Position at the company: "))
    print("\nConfirm Staff Data:\n")
    name_confirm = "Name: %s"%(name)
    position_confirm = "Position: %s"%(position)
    print(name_confirm)
    print(position_confirm)
    confirmAns = input("Is the information right? (Y/N)")
    if confirmAns == "y" or confirmAns == "Y":
        message = "\nSearching for %s"%(name)
        print(message)
        hoursWorked = int(input("Insert hours worked: "))
        if hoursWorked <= 0:
                print("Please insert a valid number")
        elif hoursWorked > 0:
                print("\nCalculete Paycheck")
                hourRate = int(input("Insert the rate of each hour worked: "))
                bonus = input("If a bonus was given insert it here: ")
                fine = input("If a fine was given insert it here: ")
                print('\n')
                payment = hoursWorked*hourRate-int(fine)+int(bonus)
                paymentMsg = "Your Payment is: $%d"%(payment)
                print(paymentMsg)
    elif confirmAns == "n" or confirmAns == "N":
        print("working")
    else:
        print("Please answer with Y or N")
    return
```

Answer (score 1):

All python code should be indented after the ':' character, in python the indentation should be 4 spaces, or people use the tab key, your code has an issue with indentation which I can't be bothered finding;

for example a 'class'

```
class this_is_a_class():
    #indentation
    #code goes here
    pass
```

or a 'for loop' or 'while loop';

```
numbers = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
for number in numbers:
    #indentation
    print(number)

x = 0
while x < 10:
    #indentation
    x += 1
    print('This is going to print 10 times')
```

or an 'if statement';

```
true_boolean = True
if true_boolean:
    #indentation
    print(True)
```

or a 'function';

```
def function():
    #indentation
    print('You have called a function')
```

What is actually happening, is python is reading through your code 'Token' by token and 'interpreting' what your code does. But considering you don't know what a function is; gloss over this paragraph.

Now for your question about how functions work. A function is used organize code. You can call a function multiple times, which makes your code more organized and easier to work with, this is why as your code got longer, you ran into this problem; Lets for example say i wanted to print 'hello world' 10 times.

I could write this code on 10 seperate lines;

```
print("hello world")
print("hello world")
#etc... More chance for error
```

or I could use a function and call it 10 times;

```
def say_hello_world():
    #indentation
    print("hello world")

for each_call in range(0,10):
    say_hello_world() #This is the function call
```

You can also pass 'arguments into a function' for example;

```
def say_hello(person):
    #indentation
    print('hello', person)

say_hello('Alex')
```

Now any words that are in quotations in this answer can be google searched with the word 'python' and you can find out much more about how python works.

I hope this gets you started with python. Although all of these concepts can be used in other programming languages.